# Please ensure that at least one realm can authenticate these tokens

Tags: java, authentication, shiro

So I have set up my shiro to have two Realms.  A Username and Password Realm, using the standard UsernamePasswordToken.  I have also set up a Custom Bearer Authentication Token that works off a token passed in from the user.

If i just use my passwordValidatorRealm it works find, if no user is found throws unknown account, if password doesn’t match throws incorrect credentials, perfect.  But as soon as i put in my tokenValidatorRealm it throws a

```
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication token of type [class org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken] could not be authenticated by any configured realms.
```

In this instance my tokenValidatorRealm  returns null as no token was provided, so it moves on to the passwordValidatorRealm and just breaks.

Any ideas why introducing a second Realm will cause my working passwordValidatorRealm to break?

Have tried with different authentication strategies, and no luck there.

Using shiro 1.2.2

EDIT

I have two implementations, one for password and one for token

Password:

```
public class PasswordAuthorizingRealm extends AuthenticatingRealm {

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (authenticationToken instanceof UsernamePasswordToken) {
        UsernamePasswordToken usernamePasswordToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) authenticationToken;
        String username = usernamePasswordToken.getUsername();
        char[] password = usernamePasswordToken.getPassword();

        if (username == null) {
            throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm!");
        }
        //Null password is invalid
        if (password == null) {
            throw new AccountException("Null passwords are not allowed by this realm!");
        }

        UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnknownAccountException("Could not authenticate with given credentials");
        }

        SimpleAuthenticationInfo simpleAuthenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, user.getPassword(), "passwordValidatorRealm");

        return simpleAuthenticationInfo;

    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

and Bearer Token

```
public class TokenAuthorizingRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (authenticationToken instanceof BearerAuthenticationToken) {

        BearerAuthenticationToken bearerAuthenticationToken = (BearerAuthenticationToken) authenticationToken;

        String username = "" + bearerAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        //User with such username has not found
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnknownAccountException("Could not authenticate with given credentials");
        }
        BearerAuthenticationInfo bearerAuthenticationInfo = new BearerAuthenticationInfo(user);
        return bearerAuthenticationInfo;

    }

 }
```

Shiro config

```
[main]

hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 500000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true

hashService.privateSalt = ****

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

authc = my.BearerTokenAuthenticatingFilter

tokenValidatorRealm = my.TokenAuthorizingRealm
passwordValidatorRealm = my.PasswordAuthorizingRealm

passwordValidatorRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher

securityManager.realms = $tokenValidatorRealm,$passwordValidatorRealm
```

These have been stripped out a bit, removed logging and other unnecessary code

The BearerTokenAuthenticatingFilter, just basically checks if a token has been supplied in the header if has

```
private void loginUser(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    BearerAuthenticationToken token = (BearerAuthenticationToken) createToken(request, response);

    if (token == null) {
        String msg = "createToken method implementation returned null. A valid non-null AuthenticationToken "
                + "must be created in order to execute a login attempt.";
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
    }

    try {
        Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
        subject.login(token);
        onLoginSuccess(token, subject, request, response);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = WebUtils.toHttp(response);
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("login");
    }
}
```

BearerAuthenticationInfo class

```
public class BearerAuthenticationInfo implements AuthenticationInfo {

private final PrincipalCollection principalCollection;
private final User user;

public BearerAuthenticationInfo(User user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.principalCollection = buildPrincipalCollection(user);
}

public PrincipalCollection getPrincipals() {
    return principalCollection;

}

public Object getCredentials() {
    return user.getUsername();
}

private PrincipalCollection buildPrincipalCollection(User user) {
    Collection<String> principals = new ArrayList<String>();
    principals.add(user.getUsername());
    return new SimplePrincipalCollection(principals, "tokenValidatorRealm");
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share your realms doGetAuthenticationInfo implementation and how you call login with us?

Comment: Have updated original post with additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is expected behavior.

If you look at the javadoc for ModularRealmAuthenticator:

```
 * @throws AuthenticationException if the user could not be authenticated or the user is denied authentication
 *                                 for the given principal and credentials.
 */
protected AuthenticationInfo doAuthenticate(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
```

If you are having problems with the exception, you might need to change the code that calls the authentication to expect this exception.

---

Left for other searches:

You might have a missing supports method in your TokenAuthorizingRealm class.

Something like

```
@Override
public boolean supports(AuthenticationToken token) {
    return token instanceof BearerAuthenticationToken;
}
```

should be present.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that in the above code, I have the supports method in both my implementations.  I did also try in the token implementation constructor to run     setAuthenticationTokenClass(BearerAuthenticationToken.class);     but this had no effect

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seen that actually the support methods are being called on both realm implementations?

Comment: Yip both are being called. Token first (as specified in ini to be first) and returns false.  Then password which returns true.

Comment: Ok and does the debugging of the doGetAuthenticationInfo method in the password give any extra insights, does it get called?

Comment: Nope :( it makes it all the way through and returns me my simpleAuthenticationInfo (which isn't null), and then still throws 'Please ensure that at least one realm can authenticate these tokens.'.  If i disable the use of the TokenAuthorizingRealm in my ini, it also makes it all the way through but i get the accurate exception (UnknownAccountException or IncorrectCredentialsException...)

Comment: Can you share the code for BearerAuthenticationInfo?

Comment: Have updated original post with BearerAuthenticationInfo

Comment: Hmm that looks good too. Try putting a breakpoint in the class AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy in the if statement to see why it is actually throwing it. Does it get the BearerAuthenticationInfo?

Comment: When logging in with username and password the BearerAuthenticationInfo does not get called.  When authenticating with a token it does it get called and returns as expected. Am putting debug into AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy now, will reply when done

Comment: I put some debug into the AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy class.  The method afterAllAttempts(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo aggregate), the token come through as a 'org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken' the aggregate is Null.  So this seems to be causing the problem.  Any ideas as to why the aggregate will be null.  I don't implement my own Authentication Strategy, i use the default one supplied

Comment: Try more debugging, this time in class ModularRealmAuthenticator, debug doMultiRealmAuthentication. That is the one making the aggregate. See if you can find out which realm causes it to become null.

Comment: Ok so in doMultiRealmAuthentication.  It enters with both my realms and org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken.  then the first call to get aggregate    AuthenticationInfo aggregate = strategy.beforeAllAttempts(realms, token);returns

Comment: Ok so in doMultiRealmAuthentication.  It enters in with both my realms (token and password) and org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken.  then the first call to get aggregate    AuthenticationInfo aggregate = strategy.beforeAllAttempts(realms, token);    returns null.  it then enters the realm loop, the first one is my token realms and it skips is, the second is the password so it tries    aggregate = strategy.beforeAttempt(realm, token, aggregate);   which also returns null.  then the if (realm supports token)    aggregate = strategy.afterAttempt(realm, token, info, aggregate, t);

Comment: (continuation)
is called and again this is null.  

Basically all calls to get an aggregate return null.  Any further suggestions

Comment: Did you step into the beforeAttempt and afterAttempt methods to see why it returns null? The answer must be somewhere over there

Comment: Ok so I have tracked it back to ModularRealmAuthenticator.doMultiRealmAuthentication.  'info = realm.getAuthenticationInfo(token);'  this throws the exception org.apache.shiro.authc.IncorrectCredentialsException: Submitted credentials for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - bob, rememberMe=false] did not match the expected credentials.  Which comes from AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo  assertCredentialsMatch(token, info);  This is now basically saying that my credentials don’t match, which is correct.

Comment: I don’t know if I was descriptive enough in my initial brief, I only get the exception as described in my first post if I put in incorrect credentials, if I use the correct credentials it logs me in fine.  So why does this not throw an incorrect credentials as it does when I only have one realm configured.

Comment: So let me get this straight. The scenario with 2 realms with incorrect credentials is as you expect it, but the first scenario 1 with realm just authenticates your user when you enter incorrect credentials and that is the real problem?

Comment: Not exactly, it works fine with one realm, throwing the correct exceptions for each scenario, UnknownAccountException, IncorrectCredentialsException, ...  With the two realms configured it works fine when logging in with the correct credentials, but as soon as incorrect credentials, it throws     AuthenticationException: Authentication token of type [class org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken] could not be authenticated by any configured realms.

Comment: It is expected behavior then. What it says is exactly that the token CANNOT be authenticated by ANY SUPPORTED realms. Meaning the password is incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

This discussion help me solve a similar problem. I wanted to authenticate a user by the application itself, not using any Shiro default implementation. To do that we must subclass AuthenticatingRealm, override doGetAuthenticationInfo and declare this realm as the validation one.

```
public class PasswordAuthorizingRealm extends AuthenticatingRealm {

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
```

In Shiro.ini:

```
passwordValidatorRealm = my.PasswordAuthorizingRealm
```