# How to authenticate user in Java code with database

Tags: java, shiro

I would like to use Apache Shiro with database authentication. But I can't make database design changes. I would like to use my custom SQL command and Java logic to authenticate user. Is this possible? I tried this configuration in shiro.ini:

saltedJdbcRealm=com.crm.web.authentication.JdbcRealm

And custom Java class:

```
public class JdbcRealm extends AuthorizingRealm
{
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected static final String DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select passwd from user where username = ?";

    protected static final String DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select passwd, passwd_salt from user where username = ?";

    protected static final String DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY = "select role_name from user_roles where username = ?";

    protected static final String DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?";
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcRealm.class);

    public enum SaltStyle
    {
        NO_SALT, CRYPT, COLUMN, EXTERNAL
    };
    protected String authenticationQuery = DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY;
    protected String userRolesQuery = DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY;
    protected String permissionsQuery = DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY;
    protected boolean permissionsLookupEnabled = false;

    protected SaltStyle saltStyle = SaltStyle.NO_SALT;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationQuery(String authenticationQuery)
    {
        this.authenticationQuery = authenticationQuery;
    }

    public void setUserRolesQuery(String userRolesQuery)
    {
        this.userRolesQuery = userRolesQuery;
    }

    public void setPermissionsQuery(String permissionsQuery)
    {
        this.permissionsQuery = permissionsQuery;
    }

    public void setPermissionsLookupEnabled(boolean permissionsLookupEnabled)
    {
        this.permissionsLookupEnabled = permissionsLookupEnabled;
    }

    public void setSaltStyle(SaltStyle saltStyle)
    {
        this.saltStyle = saltStyle;
        if (saltStyle == SaltStyle.COLUMN && authenticationQuery.equals(DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY))
        {
            authenticationQuery = DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        String username = upToken.getUsername();
        // Null username is invalid
        if (username == null)
        {
            throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.");
        }
        Connection conn = null;
        SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = null;
        try
        {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String password = null;
            String salt = null;
            switch (saltStyle)
            {
                case NO_SALT:
                    password = getPasswordForUser(conn, username)[0];
                    break;
                case CRYPT:
                    // TODO: separate password and hash from getPasswordForUser[0]
                    throw new ConfigurationException("Not implemented yet");
                //break;
                case COLUMN:
                    String[] queryResults = getPasswordForUser(conn, username);
                    password = queryResults[0];
                    salt = queryResults[1];
                    break;
                case EXTERNAL:
                    password = getPasswordForUser(conn, username)[0];
                    salt = getSaltForUser(username);
            }
            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
            }
            info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, password.toCharArray(), getName());

            if (salt != null)
            {
                info.setCredentialsSalt(ByteSource.Util.bytes(salt));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            final String message = "There was a SQL error while authenticating user [" + username + "]";
            if (log.isErrorEnabled())
            {
                log.error(message, e);
            }
            throw new AuthenticationException(message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return info;
    }

    private String[] getPasswordForUser(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException
    {
        String[] result;
        boolean returningSeparatedSalt = false;
        switch (saltStyle)
        {
            case NO_SALT:
            case CRYPT:
            case EXTERNAL:
                result = new String[1];
                break;
            default:
                result = new String[2];
                returningSeparatedSalt = true;
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(authenticationQuery);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            // Execute query
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // Loop over results - although we are only expecting one result, since usernames should be unique
            boolean foundResult = false;
            while (rs.next())
            {
                // Check to ensure only one row is processed
                if (foundResult)
                {
                    throw new AuthenticationException("More than one user row found for user [" + username + "]. Usernames must be unique.");
                }
                result[0] = rs.getString(1);
                if (returningSeparatedSalt)
                {
                    result[1] = rs.getString(2);
                }
                foundResult = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)
    {
        //null usernames are invalid
        if (principals == null)
        {
            throw new AuthorizationException("PrincipalCollection method argument cannot be null.");
        }
        String username = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);
        Connection conn = null;
        Set<String> roleNames = null;
        Set<String> permissions = null;
        try
        {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            // Retrieve roles and permissions from database
            roleNames = getRoleNamesForUser(conn, username);
            if (permissionsLookupEnabled)
            {
                permissions = getPermissions(conn, username, roleNames);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            final String message = "There was a SQL error while authorizing user [" + username + "]";
            if (log.isErrorEnabled())
            {
                log.error(message, e);
            }
            // Rethrow any SQL errors as an authorization exception
            throw new AuthorizationException(message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
        info.setStringPermissions(permissions);
        return info;
    }

    protected Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Set<String> roleNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(userRolesQuery);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            // Execute query
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // Loop over results and add each returned role to a set
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String roleName = rs.getString(1);
                // Add the role to the list of names if it isn't null
                if (roleName != null)
                {
                    roleNames.add(roleName);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (log.isWarnEnabled())
                    {
                        log.warn("Null role name found while retrieving role names for user [" + username + "]");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return roleNames;
    }

    protected Set<String> getPermissions(Connection conn, String username, Collection<String> roleNames) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Set<String> permissions = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(permissionsQuery);
            for (String roleName : roleNames)
            {
                ps.setString(1, roleName);
                ResultSet rs = null;
                try
                {
                    // Execute query
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    // Loop over results and add each returned role to a set
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        String permissionString = rs.getString(1);
                        // Add the permission to the set of permissions
                        permissions.add(permissionString);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return permissions;
    }

    protected String getSaltForUser(String username)
    {
        return username;
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication token of type [class org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken] could not be authenticated by any configured realms.  Please ensure that at least one realm can authenticate these tokens.
```

Am I missing some configuration in shiro.ini

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353445/please-ensure-that-at-least-one-realm-can-authenticate-these-tokens

Comment: I don't see anything useful for my case.

Comment: I don't know Shiro but first thing I would check is the classpath, have you included your custom class into the Shiro classpath?

Comment: Yes. classpath is working fine.

Comment: Put your shiro.ini at your question. Looks like you need more configuration. I reccommend you to extend https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.4/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html instead of AuthorizingRealm.

Answer (score 4):

This is how we do it in XML(shiro.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean id="logout" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter">
        <property name="redirectUrl" value="YOUR_LOGIN_URL" />
    </bean>
     <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="YOUR_SUCCESS_URL"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="YOUR_ACCESS_DENIED_URL"/>

    <property name="filters">
      <util:map>
        <entry key="logout" value-ref="logout"/>
       </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
        /** = authc <!--SPECIFY_OTHERS_FILTERS_CHAINS-->
        </value>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="builtInCacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <!-- Single realm app.  If you have multiple realms, use the 'realms' property instead. -->
    <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="builtInCacheManager"/>
    <!-- By default the servlet container sessions will be used.  Uncomment this line-->
         <!-- to use shiro's native sessions (see the JavaDoc for more): -->
    <!-- <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/> -->
</bean>
<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Define the Shiro Realm implementation you want to use to connect to your back-end -->
<!-- security datasource: -->
<bean id="myRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm">
    <property name="credentialsMatcher" ref="hashMatcher"/> 
     <property name="authenticationQuery" value="select password from user_login where user_id = ?"/>
     <property name="userRolesQuery" value="YOUR_ROLE_QUERY"/>

     <property name="permissionsQuery" value="YOUR_PERMISSION_QUERY" />
     <property name="permissionsLookupEnabled" value="true"></property>
     <property name="dataSource" ref="YOUR_DATA_SOURCE_NAME"/> <!-- i.e. being used for the DB connection -->
</bean>

<!-- Hash Matcher Bean responsible for matching credentials of logging user -->
<bean id="hashMatcher" class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher">
<!--        Algorithm name -->
    <property name="hashAlgorithmName" value="SHA-512"/> 

<!--        No. of Hash Iterations. Note: must match with iterations used to save password in database. -->
    <property name="hashIterations" value="10000"/>  
<!--        true if Stored Credentials(i.e. password and salt) are in Hexadecimal form. False denotes BASE64 encoding.-->
    <property name="storedCredentialsHexEncoded" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable Shiro Annotations for Spring-configured beans.  Only run after -->
<!-- the lifecycleBeanProcessor has run: -->
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

You can include it in the application config file (web.xml)

Answer (score 2):

All shiro needs to mark session as authenticated is AuthenticationInfo object. How it's built is up to you. 
The realm should be tied to the security manager.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give you 2 suggestions. Hope it will help you.

### Suggestion - 1:

Configuration file is not fully configured for Realm.
You should write a class for AuthorizingRealm, then the class will be configured to configuration file.

If you use the spring, then the configuration will look like below:

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="localRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="localRealm" class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.infra.LocalSecurityRealm">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="securityApplication" />
</bean>
```

Add authenticator in `shiro.ini` configuration file

```
authenticator = com.realm.MyRealm
```

### Resource Link:

1. http://www.oschina.net/question/617087_72790#answers

---

### Suggestion - 2:

You need to  first make sure that `supports()` are actually reached and executed.

```
  @Override
  public boolean supports(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
    return (authenticationToken instanceof UsernamePasswordToken)
  }
```

If you have multiple realms and one throws an error, the others will NOT be processed.
So if you need to work around thrown Exceptions you can do something like [this](https://github.com/dzinevich/nexus/blob/master/components/nexus-security/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/authz/ExceptionCatchingModularRealmAuthorizer.java) for authz and [this](https://github.com/dzinevich/nexus/blob/master/components/nexus-security/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/authc/FirstSuccessfulModularRealmAuthenticator.java) for authc.

### Resource Link:

1. http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Still-having-an-issue-with-multiple-realms-td7579698.html